# Has the light from the Star Wars galaxy reached us yet?

Tags: star-wars

Star Wars is set a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away. Has Earth received the light from any of those events yet?

Comment: I would say this is not POB, since it’s possible that (now or later) there will be some timeline of *Star Wars* relative to whatever fictional Earth exists in the *Star Wars* universe, which makes this potentially answerable based on facts/informed extrapolation.

Comment: but @Adamant - isn't it opinion based still unless Lucas or Disney or Pablo points at the sky and says "that's the one - that's the galaxy" - until we know *which* galaxy it's impossible to truly say, no?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From ["The Galaxy" on the Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_galaxy)

> Nothing connects the Star Wars galaxy with ours (the Milky Way), other than that Humans have developed in both, but this coincidence has never been implied to be anything other than independent evolutionary processes. However, if we are to consider a crossover between Star Wars and E.T. based on the mention of Brodo Asogi and its extra-galactic expedition, we can infer the following: the Brodo Asogi Senator, Grebleips, sent an expedition to another galaxy. This may have been our galaxy, and we can assume that is how E.T. ended up on Earth. The movie says that E.T. is a being three million light years from home (our galaxy is approximately 100,000 light years wide and its closest neighbor (Andromeda) is approximately 2.5 million light years away), so his home planet has to be in another galaxy other than the Milky Way or Andromeda, perhaps the Star Wars galaxy. E.T.'s home galaxy would therefore be part of the Local Group and the Virgo Supercluster at approximately a megaparsec away from us. However, this would mean, E.T.'s home galaxy (and, possibly, the Star Wars galaxy) would not be, on a universal scale, a galaxy far, far away but one of approximately forty galaxies that are our "neighbors". In any case, the fictional Star Wars galaxy is (at least theoretically) on the same plane of existence as ours, as it is a supposedly finite distance of "far, far away" from the Milky Way.

That would suggest that the light from the Star Wars galaxy would reach Earth roughly 3 million years after the events in Star Wars. Unless the ET species has lived for more than 3 million years after the events of Star Wars, we can assume that the light from that galaxy has yet to reach us.

Comment: A 3 million year gap is totally plausible for a 'long long time' The dinosaurs were 65 million years ago, and the earth is a very new solar system in galactic terms: an older galaxy could easily have advanced intelligent life 3 million years ago, so I'd go with 'plausible'

Comment: @Canageek the part I find hard to believe is that the expedition talked about would take 3 million years to get to Earth. That's one looong expedition. Therefore, it is most likely that the E.T. species managed to find super-fast FTL travel and made it to earth much faster than in 3 million years. Even with the existing SW tech and Han Solo's claimed ".5 past light speed" you are talking about shaving 1 million years off the journey. So the answer is still no.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread something; good point.

Comment: Do we know how big the Star Wars galaxy is? I'm looking at the [list of nearby galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_galaxies). Andromeda (M31) is 2.56 million light-years away, a bit too close to be referred to as "3 million". Triangulum (M33) is 2.64 million -- more plausible, but still a bit close. Other galaxies in the 3 million light-year range are dwarf galaxies and/or satellites of Andromeda.

Comment: @KeithThompson Just to note, since Andromeda is moving towards us, it must have been further away in the past.  In a few billion years it will merge with the Milky Way galaxy, so perhaps a billion years ago or more it was 3 million light years away, and that's when the story took place.

Comment: But Star Wars was also a "long time ago", and it's also possible that life there skipped the dinosaur stage or simply evolved faster. I'm not sure if Star Wars has a stardate, but maybe it took place millions of years ago and the light has already reached us?

Comment: The notion that Humans developed in the Star Wars galaxy as humans is more Alien to me then every single species in the Star Wars universe pu together. I don't know how to explain it, It just sounds weird....