# Are E.T. and Star Wars in the same universe?

Tags: star-wars, et-the-extra-terrestrial, shared-universe

An answer [about the Star Wars timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/has-the-star-wars-universe-caught-up-to-our-time/6331#6331), uses the appearance of E.T.-like creatures in the Star Wars universe as a frame of reference for dating the sagas relative to our present day.

I remember noticing, and discussing the E.T.-like creatures when I saw the film, too, but is there an in-universe explanation for this, or an in-universe tying of the two stories?

Or is it just a cute Hollywood nod on the part of *Star Wars* to the *E.T.* franchise?

Comment: HoloNet News Vol. 531 50 also mentions that Senator Grebleips of Brodo Asogi funded an expedition to another galaxy. This is another reference to E.T., since E.T. visits Earth from another galaxy in the film. But isn't star wars long long ago?

Comment: @nonoway: Yes, but it is far far away, so it might take a while to get here...

Comment: In the movie E.T., there is a scene when the kids are out for Halloween where we see [a kid wearing a Yoda costume](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Yoda_in_ET.jpg). To me, this is proof that Star Wars is fiction within the E.T. universe. I'd post this as an answer but I don't have the requisite 10 rep from this stack exchange.

Comment: Considering that there are *humans* in the freakin' Star Wars universe, then the appearance of E.T.'s should hardly be shocking.

Comment: @alex.jordan yeah, and i bet you believe aliens never landed in Roswell. :) Just because people call it fiction does not mean it never happened. Remember, ST happen a long long time ago, and as user3227 points out, there were expeditions to other galaxies *even back then*. It is  likely one such expedition made it to earth and told the story to ET's George Lucas.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**TL;DR answer**: Yes. As a gag/easter egg/cross-merchandizing/friendly jest/whatever, Spielberg and Lucas have placed enough canon information in their universes to imply
that E.T. really is an alien from a species in a Star Wars Galaxy.

---

The two directors (Spielberg and Lucas) went to film school together (Where they made THX 1138).  Since they knew each other and have worked together in the past it is also very plausible they collaborated with each other about E.T. being part of Star Wars.

---

E.T.'s species were officially called **[The Children of the Green Planet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Green_Planet)**, their planet was called **[Brodo Asogi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Brodo_Asogi)**

---

**Background on the cross-over history**:

> **The Children of the Green Planet** are a cameo appearance of the famous aliens of Steven Spielberg's 1982 film E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial. These creatures were inserted in the movie to make good on a promise—after Steven Spielberg included a Yoda cameo and Star Wars toys in E.T., George Lucas promised to include an E.T. cameo in the next Star Wars film he made — The Phantom Menace.

Note: in this answer, any quotes are from Wikia article linked above, slightly reworded and improved.

---

**Main Link #1: Visual evidence:**

This is what ET looks like:

[image] [image]

In "*Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace*", in the Galactic Senate, we see the image of the senators from Brogo Asogi (not named in the movie) - who look 100% like E.T:

[image]

---

**Main Link #2: Species/planet name:**

- "*[E.T.: The Book of the Green Planet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743216407)*" (a book from E.T. franchise which is the sequel to movie's novelization) mentions on page 19 that **Brodo Asogi** was one of many names given to E.T.'s homeworld, all of which translate to "Green Planet", and "**Children of the Green Planet**" to be the translated name of E.T.'s species.
- In Star Wars Universe, the same homeworld name is given to the species in *Cloak of Deception book* (but the species name is not specified).
- The species is named in HoloNet News Vol. 531 50 which mentions Senator Grebleips<sup>*</sup> of Brodo Asogi.

---

**Other links:**

First, the "easter egg - Star Wars in ET" that started the whole crossover:

> When E.T. goes trick-or-treating with the children, he spots a child in a Yoda mask and begins to follow that child saying "Home… home…" (Composer John Williams included a snippet of his "Yoda Theme" from The Empire Strikes Back to accompany this scene.). This could be interpreted as E.T. recognizing a familiar species from his home galaxy.

Additional SW links to ET:

> HoloNet News Vol. 531 50 also mentions that Senator Grebleips of Brodo Asogi funded an expedition to another galaxy. This is another reference to E.T., since E.T. visits Earth from another galaxy in the film.
>
> Pat Welsh, the woman who did the voice for E.T. in E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial, also did the voice for the bounty hunter Boushh in Star Wars Episode VI: Return of the Jedi.

<sup>*Several people have made mention of the fact that 'Grebleips' is 'Spielberg' spelled backwards, as another related easter-egg.</sup>

Comment: For further confirmation from Lucas himself, please see @Beofett's [excellent answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13035/976)

Comment: Steven Spielberg were very close, in fact he directed some scenes from revenge of the sith, according a J.W. rinzler's book: The Making of Star wars Revenge of the sith. (I'll admit my memory of that book is fuzzy, it has been a while since I last read). I very vaguely remember it was originally an idea hatched by the artists at ILM... You can all check for you selfs, its a worthwhile book to read.

Answer (score 64):

To expand upon DVK's excellent answer, I have found a source that confirms that the species shown in TPM are, in fact, the same species as in E.T.: [an interview with George Lucas himself](http://www.supershadow.com/george_lucas/interview/33.html) (emphasis mine):

> A greeting and suggestion from Denmark. In The Phantom Menace, there
>   is a cameo appearance in one of the senate chamber boxes, by some of
>   the E.T.'s. As in Steven Spielberg's E.T.: The Extraterrestrial movie.
>   Since they must be an established race in the Star Wars universe,
>   there wouldn't be anything wrong in having them in another cameo
>   role(s), either in the new Star Wars TV series or in future films.
>   With Spielberg's acceptance, of course. Since they are a race devoted
>   to science and exploration, they could easily fit into the known Star
>   Wars universe.
>
> ...
>
> **George Lucas**: The problem is that the E.T. design is owned by
>   Universal Studios. ***Steven and Universal let me show the E.T.'s for a
>   fraction of a second***, but we wouldn't actually ever use them in one of
>   the upcoming Star Wars TV shows or the future films. We have plenty of
>   new types of aliens to reveal and don't need to give any further
>   screen time to E.T.'s species.

Comment: It's obvious out of universe that they are the same. In universe it is less clear, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @RCToaster Actually, some people were arguing that there wasn't enough evidence, even with the previously listed out-of-universe sources, to claim they were the same.  E.g. the answer below claims that we don't know if they even look the same from the waste-down. While not citing anything depicted directly in the universe, it does qualify as a ["Word of God"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1546/1359) answer, and therefore may be considered a legitimate in-universe explanation.

Comment: Note the accepted answer to this [meta question discussing what constitutes in-universe](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1541/1359) explicitly states interviews can be in-universe explanations, so if the downvotes are because people feel my answer is out-of-universe, I invite the voters to participate in the meta, as our current policy implies otherwise.

Comment: @Beofett - since my answer garnered 8 DVs, I suspect that your downvoters are more likely people who think that there is no link, and "it's ridiculous to suggest otherwise". +1 from me, and frankly your proof is better than my answer.

Answer (score 15):

The evidence for ET and Star Wars sharing a universe is far from conclusive.

Going by strictly canon material from the movies, all we have is a picture of aliens that resemble ET from the waist up, which DVK provided a picture of.

We don't know that they resemble ET in full or that even if they do, they are in fact the same species. It would be easy to mistake a Centari for example for a Human.

Most of the evidence for them being in the same universe comes from the extended universe or non-canon work. For example, Senator Grebleips funding a trip to another galaxy does not necessarily have anything to do with the trip made by ET.

There are enough points there that you can link things together and draw a somewhat reasonable conclusion that ET and Star Wars *may* share a universe.

On the other hand, a clear example of a mask of Yoda is seen in E.T. This could void any theory on sharing a universe, but could also simply be an easter egg to help viewers make the connection.

[image]

This means that any similarities between ET and an alien race in the Star Wars galaxy is just a coincidence. Star Wars is firmly fiction within the ET universe, so cannot by definition share the same universe.

Comment: Why can't the existence of Star Wars in ET be the coincidence? Or why can't it be a documentary? Or perhaps is was assembled from found-footage by the government to ready the human race for meeting real aliens?

Comment: Since SW plays not only in a galaxy far, far away, but also a long time ago, one could _speculate_ that ET's species has since travelled to our galaxy, and the Earthlings' SW franchise is the echo of a subconscious memory of said galaxy far, far away...