# Are Star Wars and Indiana Jones in the same galaxy, far, far away?

Tags: star-wars, indiana-jones

Despite the fact that Han Solo and Dr. Jones look eerily similar, did the Star Wars saga occur in Jones' galaxy (and thus Jones not being in our own)? The question stems from a few references in Jones' world: The hieroglyphics in *Raiders* showing C-3PO and R2D2 and the bar in *Temple* named Club Obi-Wan.

[image: Indiana Jones prepares to remove the rock lid covering the Ark of the Covenant. A gilded pillar to his right is engraved with heiroglyphics, including, circled, what appears to be a representation of R2-D2 and C-3PO.]

Comment: Sometimes an Easter egg is just an Easter egg.

Comment: Can't a guy dream? :P

Comment: Droids... why did it have to be droids????

Comment: To clarify: was the word "Galaxy" literally meaning "Galaxy" astronomically speaking, or did you imply "Universe"?

Comment: @DVK given that the word galaxy is followed by "far, far away" as a quantifier, I think it is clear he does not mean universe in the sense of show/movie universes.

Comment: @Kristy - correct, I was talking astrononical universe

Comment: But, what is the eye of Sauron doing under them?!

Comment: They **DO** look similar. I never noticed that. It's eerie.

Comment: Kristy and DVK are both right
============================= DVK clearly demonstrated that they are in the same *Universe* because E.T.'s species is present in both. But the fact that E.T. came from another galaxy demonstrates that Indy's and Star Wars galaxies are not the same. So, same universe, different galaxy.

Comment: @algogia That should probably be an answer, not a comment (yes, I see Thaddeus moved your answer to a comment. In which case, it should probably be neither :) )

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No.

Indy has far too many references to Earth specific events and objects to be a coincidence. The World Wars, The Ark of the Covenant, Nazis, Harvard University, Venice, planes, automobiles, trains, rifles, pistols, swords, whips...

The maps in the movie also show pretty clearly that they are on earth. The maps are quite iconic although I can't seem to find a sample image at the moment.

For another planet in another galaxy to have a planet with the same layout of continents, with the same countries with the same cities with the same names, with the same technology and the same universities and the same religions...it's all a bit much.

As for the references to star wars characters, it is either a coincidence and we are mistaking the hieroglyphs for looking like those characters when they are something else, such as a guy in a type of armor and some kind of false idol/utility --  or those characters (or similar models) somehow made it to visit the ancient civilizations that made those hieroglyphs, through an adventure we have not yet seen.

Comment: Excellent answer :)

Comment: You are 100% wrong, sorry. E.T. is on the same "real" Earth as Indiana Jones. See my asnwer below for the details.

Comment: @DVK 100% wrong is quite strong, especially when ET sharing the same universe as SW is a) irrelivant and b) not 100% conclusive.

Comment: In the absence of clarification  from OP of "galaxy or universe", since your answer is 100% categorical "No" and mine is 100% categorical "Yes", one of our answers is clearly wrong.

Comment: @DVK your answer only makes sense if you take galaxy to mean canonical universe, since there is only one astronomical universe that we know of. Given that the OP uses far far away as a quantifier, it is a sure bet they do not mean universe(astronomical or canonical) when they say galaxy.

Comment: The images of R2-D2 and C-3PO are there intentionally, and although it isn't the same galaxy, it is definitely the same universe.  There was actually a comic book in which Han Solo and Chewbacca went to earth and were discovered by Indiana Jones, and Chewbacca became the inspiration for the myths about Big Foot and the Yeti.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are in the same Universe (though, as others noted, not in the same *galaxy*).

It was already established that E.T. (which takes place on real Earth) and Star Wars **[are in the same Universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe/6558#6558)**.

Since it seems fairly obvious that E.T. Earth is the same one as Indy Earth, they are both in the Star Wars Universe.

However, the specific hieroglyphs are, indeed, likely unrelated. There are plenty of ancient drawings that are interpreted as all sorts of paleo contacts, if one tries to look at them from weird enough angles.

Comment: Obvious? How so? (re: E.T. earth = Indy earth)

Comment: The question is whether they're in the same *galaxy*, not the same universe.

Comment: I feel bad downvoting your answer, DVK, but you clearly misread the question.

Comment: @Plutor, Keith - While I may be wrong literally, I'm 99% sure the asker meant "Universe" when he used that quote

Comment: @DVK: There you go: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12172/2565

Comment: @bitmask - Thanks :)   You could have posted the answer yourself you know :)

Comment: @DVK: If I could've, I would've. Also, it's your answer ;)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Neither E.T. nor Indiana Jones takes place on real Earth. They are fiction. Different fictional Earths are not the same--for example, different things happen in the 1990s in Star Trek and the New World of Darkness. I'm downvoting until it can be established that E.T. Earth = Indy Earth.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how credible you find the comic books, the answer is yes. In *Star Wars Tales* #19:

> In this short story, Han and Chewie are on the run from the Imperial fleet and, as a desperation move, force the *Millennium Falcon* to complete a blind hyperspace jump. The jump deposits them in our solar system (which Han doesn't recognize), and the Falcon crash lands in the American Northwest. Han comments on its resemblance to Endor, and the two smugglers set out to find a settlement. A Native American tribe sees the duo and riddles Han with a flurry of arrows. After Chewbacca butchers Han's assailants, Han dies, leaving the Wookiee on Earth all by his lonesome.

Then, this happens...

[image: The page opens with "126 years later." Silhouettes of a person carrying a gun, a man in a hat with a coiled whip, and small person or boy walk down a slope in front of a waterfall dropping between two crags into a cloud of mist. The person in the lead, in a fringed jacket, tan pants and a red neckerchief turns back, pointing to the right saying "This way, doctor. For the past thirty years, the sightings have been concentrated on this ridge." He squats, having moved his rifle to his left hand and measures a footprint with his right hand. "Here, another footprint. We're nearing his home." The man in the hat, his face in shadow, replies "Good. The museum isn't paying for footprints," as the guide (whose long face we can now see; he has a matching red headband and light blue earing) proceeds to the right. The guide leads the trio around a massive tree trunk as the small person, in a red top and blue pants leaps a rock to follow. The guides says "There must be a cave here or..." The guide looks up at the sun shining down between tall tree trunks, illuminating the Millennium Falcon's cockpit draped in vines. "This is no cave," he says.]

[image: The man in the hat helps the person in the red jacket up onto the Falcon's ramp. Once they are inside he says "What is this place?" The man in the hat, gun in hand, replies "I don't know. I've never seen anything like it. Not even in Atlantis." Standing in the cockpit, he looks at a seated skeleton in white shirt and black vest, with an arrow in his chest. Indy says "But it's all somehow familiar. Stay close, Shorty." He touches the arrow; "He looks human. Poor Bastard." The boy in the red jacket and a red cap asks "What now, Doctor Jones? We continue looking for this 'monster'?" Indy, looking off to the left replies "No." He continues in voice-over as we pull back and see the Millennium Falcon, stuck between a huge rock and and even larger tree, broken by the Falcon's impact. "Let's leave him as part of the great unknown." Chewie sits hunched over on a branch in the foreground, looking out at the Falcon.]

The story was called ["Into the Great Unknown"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Into_the_Great_Unknown).

Comment: I absolutely love the "This is no cave" reference there...

Answer (score 1):

If Star Wars was "a long time go in a galaxy far away" it just means that the evens of the trilogy's are happening 4 to 5000 years ago, and that at some point in their adventures, the droids end up out of their galaxy, and are recorded has hieroglyphs! It also means if Han Solo was around for the adventure and had a little fun Captain Kirk style while on earth, of course he could be Indy's many great grandfather! In fact, Earth could have been a lost human colony of the human-like races from Star Wars!