# Are Star Wars and Indiana Jones the same Universe?

Tags: star-wars, indiana-jones, shared-universe

*This is a follow-up question to [Are Star Wars and Indiana Jones in the same galaxy, far, far away?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12150/2565)*

We already know that [E.T. and Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6555/2565) are the same Universe, but that [Indiana Jones does not take place in the same galaxy as Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12152/2565). This makes room for the question whether they may at least take place in the same Universe, which is further supported by the glyphs in *Raiders* which appear to show R2 and 3PO:

[image: Indiana Jones prepares to remove the rock lid covering the Ark of the Covenant. A gilded pillar to his right is engraved with heiroglyphics, including, circled, what appears to be a representation of R2-D2 and C-3PO.]

Comment: How did you manage to spot that!!?

Comment: @AidanO: I didn't. See the question linked at the beginning.

Comment: Also, next time you watch Temple of Doom, look at the name of the bar they run out of in Hong Kong...http://www.eeggs.com/items/1539.html

Comment: I doubt Indiana Jones and Star Wars can possibly be the same Universe.  For one thing, in the Indy Universe, the God of Judaism and Christianity exists.  This seems incompatible with the existence of the Force and all that.  Unless you want to say that the Old Testament God is just some sort of powerful alien that contacted the Hebrews on Earth and gave them the Ark.

Comment: @Channel72: Wrong: In the Indiana Jones universe, there are the same religions of our universe and there are some weird things happening that these guys interpret as being acts of god. The fact that they share the same delusions as our universe doesn't make them more accurate.

Comment: Star Wars Tales #19 featured a story called "Into the Great Unknown", in which the Millenium Falcon made a wild hyperspace jump and crashed on a primitive Earth. Hundreds of years later, Chewie was the basis for the Bigfoot legends and Indiana Jones found his way into a cave (really the overgrown Falcon) and found the skeletal remains of Han Solo. MIND = BLOWN.

Comment: @bitmask - it's an easter egg... but I found proof for you. Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't likely.

It is far from conclusive that ET and Star Wars share the same universe. To draw that conclusion requires a lot of interpretation, assumptions and relying on information from non-canonical sources.

The child wearing a yoda mask in ET strongly implies that star wars is fiction in the ET universe, rendering any other assumptions that could lead to them being in the same universe moot.

While Indy-Earth and ET-Earth seem to both be set in our universe, that is the only reason to assume that they share the same universe, which isn't enough. There is nothing wrong with thinking so, but there is nothing to definitely show it to be true either.

While ET and Star Wars are not likely in the same universe, there is even less reason to think Indy and Star Wars are in the same universe, as there is nothing directly linking them. In fact, Star Wars may seem to be fiction in the Indy Earth due to the [name of a bar](https://www.eeggs.com/items/1539.html) in Temple of Doom, as pointed out by WOPR in a comment above.

So, no, there is nothing to indicate Indiana Jones and Star Wars are in the same universe.

Comment: If ET and Star Wars do not occur in the same universe, how do you explain members of ET's species appearing in a Star Wars movie, as representatives of their species on Corruscant?

Comment: @Beofett See my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe/6558#6559). Basically we only see the ET like species in Star Wars from the waist up. We don't know that they are the same species, just as Vulcans, Centari, Elves, or Jaffa are not the same as Humans. The assumption that they are comes from non canon sources. Given the Yoda mask in ET, Star Wars seems to be fiction within the ET universe.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they are in the same universe.

1. It was already established that E.T. (which takes place on real Earth) and Star Wars **[are in the same Universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe/6558#6558)**.
2. It seems fairly obvious that E.T. Earth is the same one as Indy Earth (since they are both supposed to be on our real Earth, with real Earth history etc...).

   **Therefore they are both in the Star Wars Universe.**

However, the specific hieroglyphs are, indeed, likely unrelated in-universe, at least no retcons were ever offered. Just an Easter Egg.

Please note that there are plenty of ancient drawings that are interpreted as all sorts of paleo contacts, if one tries to look at them from weird enough angles.

---

**UPDATE**: J.J. Abrams gave us another reason to think so.

As an Easter Egg, Han Solo's freighter, the Eravana, was noted in *The Force Awakens* *Incredible Cross-Sections* book to have a **cargo module 9906753**, which Han and Chewie haven't been able to open due to Sadoxxian crypto-lock.

[image: An annotation on a picture from "Incredible Cross-Sections" points to a small module: "Han and Chewie haven't been able to open Sadoxxian crypto-lock on cargo module 9906753"]

And careful observers of Indiana Jones' universe will note that crate #**9906753** contained the **Ark of the Covenant** that Indiana Jones delivered to US Government warehouse.

[image: At the end of "Raiders of the Lost Ark" a worker in blue coveralls pushes a cart with a large crate. The crate is labeled "TOP SECRET" "ARMY INTEL 9906753" "DO NOT OPEN!"]

Comment: Given that Star Wars happened "a long time ago", isn't it possible that, in some yet-unseen part of the Star Wars timeline, droids such as C3PO and R2D2 may have visited Earth in what would be our ancient history?  No ret-con would be needed then, because this is still "in the future" from the Star Wars perspective.

Comment: I'll transfer my comment from the other answer: how is it obvious that E.T. and Indy are in the same universe? I mean, I certainly see that they _could_ be, but the fact that both E.T. and Indy share Earth's real history does not seem sufficient to me to conclude that they _are_ in the same universe. If it is, then the same logic applies to pretty much every story that doesn't involve a global catastrophe. You'd have to lump in Star Trek, Stargate, LOTR... seriously, almost everything. It would extend to sitcoms and drama shows too. Even real life would then be part of the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Anything that did not have a globally impacting historical event mutually exclusive with either current history or the other universe is game. Star Trek is assumed to be our Universe, at least it was till the "predicted" timelines diverged (Eugenics wars etc...)

Comment: @update: cute!.

Comment: @bitmask - hey welcome back! Missed your great questions!

Comment: @DVK-in-exile: That's so nice to hear. Thank you. Yes, I haven't been so active in the SE network lately, but I check out SO from time to time :)

Answer (score 0):

Indiana Jones is in the same universe, in a galaxy far away, in the future.

The Knights Templar are from the line of Jedi or force attuned individuals explaining their powers, as well as anything supernatural happening, and the artifacts that have power. They don't understand or see the force the same way as the Jedi do. Their full understanding of it is non-existent, which is why their powers are not as strong and they are not Jedi. They explain it in other ways through religion. Lucas called the Jedi Templar in original scripts. Hes completely connected all franchises on purpose.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support your claims?

Comment: I find your lack of sources 'unuseful'.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I think the evidence given are that these stories are all set in our universe. My rationale for this relates to the precursor text to the opening crawl in Episode IV - A New Hope "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....”. This clearly defines two points of reference. Firstly where - A galaxy far, far away from where you are now in the cinema or in your home but in this universe where you live. Secondly the time-frame when it happened “A long time ago” so (debatably before mankind inhabited Earth, but definitely before the Ark of the Covenant appeared in Terran religious texts. This would account for the appearance of the Ark in Raiders, the hieroglyphs of R2 and 3P0 in the carvings, the bigfoot mythology, and if Han/Rey left a journal of some kind on Earth that would enable film makers to make the movies and Star Wars paraphernalia we see in ET which is set in the 1980’s after the Star Wars movie was released. It would explain it more accurately if it was Rey that the left the journal as Han would not of been able to chronicle his own demise at the hand of his son. Anything I missed. I think it makes total sense.

Comment: You've explained how they tie into our universe, not if they've been canonically shown to be in the same universe.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Well, to be fair, they are both set in our universe, then as a corollary they are set in the same universe.

Comment: Sure, but nothing has been suggested for them existing in the same universe, in the sense that IJ has been _assumed_ to have taken place in our universe as opposed to evidence showing it had.