# Is Christmas celebrated in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I am aware of such atrocities as the [holiday special](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special) or [Christmas in the Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Christmas_in_the_Stars)
but I do not count these by any stretch of the imagination to count. Are there any canon or legends mentions or references to Christmas anywhere within the galaxy?

Please label answers as canon or legends.

Comment: Merry [Life Day](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Life_Day)!

Comment: Not yet. But give Disney a couple of years....

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64305/has-any-reference-been-made-to-earth-or-the-milky-way-in-star-wars-eu

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

According to Wikipedia, Christmas is an annual festival commemorating the birth of Jesus Christ, who is a human male from planet Earth born 7-2BC.

However, a long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away:

> There is no Christ, there is the Force.

Comment: Unless, of course, you mean http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aXXvboV_700b.jpg