# Does biological evolution exist within the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Just wondering if biological evolution is addressed or even mentioned anywhere in any Canon or Legends works.

[image: Pointless, but creepy-looking, alien]

Comment: This is a very broad question, and the photo doesn't seem very relevant.

Comment: In what respect?

Comment: @Paulie_D, He just wants examples

Comment: @Edlothiad Any suggestions for making it more specific?

Comment: No, I think it's possible it might be too broad to be answered

Comment: @Edlothiad How is this scope any different from, say, [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64305/has-any-reference-been-made-to-earth-or-the-milky-way-in-star-wars-eu?rq=1)?

Comment: @Bob, no difference, I'd say that one is too broad as well. The issue is it's a massive list question. It may be acceptable, if the list is short, which is why I said it was possible.

Comment: @Bob, my issue is addressed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) but noted here : **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format
*There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: In context, the photo of Bib Fortuna seems to imply the question, "For example, how are Twi'lek head-tails anything other than a survival disadvantage?"

Comment: Is there any reason why biological evolution would **not** exist anywhere in the Star Wars galaxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gizka), which itself quotes [*The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Complete_Star_Wars_Encyclopedia), evolution exists in the Star Wars universe:

> In the *The Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia*, gizka are referred to as a "fish" which was prized by the Selkath of Manaan rather than a reptilian species. The species, according to the encyclopedia, is said to have possibly evolved from a more rabid native on Lehon about four millennia prior to the Galactic Civil War.

Comment: A more "rabid" native? As in, more prone to rabies?

Comment: @GorchestopherH - Well, of course. Fish are not prone to rabies, so it must have evolved from something that was.

Comment: @Adamant Of course, I was joking, as "rapid" can mean "having rabies" or "madly violent", having the same root word as "rave".