# Is Earth even mentioned in any Star Wars stories (including the extended universe)?

Tags: star-wars, canon

"Long ago, Galaxy far away..." and all that, but has Earth ever been mentioned in any canonical or semi-canonical SW story?

If not, are there any explanations for the origins of humans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has any reference been made to Earth or the Milky Way in Star Wars EU?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64305/has-any-reference-been-made-to-earth-or-the-milky-way-in-star-wars-eu). See also [Why are there humans in the Star Wars Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4073/98028)