# Did Q forget about Amanda Rogers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

In the *Voyager* episode [The Q and the Grey](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_and_the_Grey_%28episode%29), Q wants to have a child with Janeway because there hasn't been a new Q in billions of years and he wants to mix up the Continuum (to save it). But this statement would seem to over look Amanda Rogers from [True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29) (TNG).

Is there a canon explanation for this conflict of facts, or was this merely an oversight on the part of the writers?

Comment: Trying to research this brings up WAY too many out-of-the-weird-corner-of-Internet fanfics. +1 anyway.

Comment: @DVK ....link? >_>

Comment: @Keen - I shall most certainly refrain from being a party to disseminating such dreadful things as those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the synopsis of [True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29) that you linked to:

> [Q] then reveals that Amanda is a Q, shocking everyone else. When Crusher claims Amanda's birth parents were Human, Q reveals they were members of the Q Continuum who had assumed Human form.

I can only surmise that since both Amanda's parents were members of the Q Continuum that in that case there was no introduction of the human DNA that he was looking for with Janeway.

This is further evidenced by:

> ...the real reason for [Q's] examination was to determine if Amanda was actually a Q or some sort of hybrid that would have to be exterminated.

He is sent there to make sure that she is not a hybrid but a full "Q".

From [The Q and the Grey](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_and_the_Grey_%28episode%29):

> He then explains that he wishes to end the war by adding Human DNA into the Continuum and having a baby, something that hasn't been done before.

The episode does end with the "solution" being Q mating with a female Q, however it is not stated that this act of procreation had "never been done before" but rather that adding human DNA had not.

Edit:
As pointed out by @bitmask in the comments, there also was a difference in the erm...mating procedures for the two "Q" children. Which may lead to Q's presumption that what he was wont to do had not been done before: [E.T. and Star Wars are in the same universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe) but I don't think E.T. and Star Trek are, so the mating ritual was unique in-universe.

Comment: In addition to this explanation: It is reasonable to assume Amanda was conceived while her parents were in human form, using conventional human means. Junior however was conceived with the weird E.T. technique. So that should make a difference.

Comment: The fact that having a child with Lady Q appeased Q's desire for a child makes me wonder whether the desire for human DNA was actual, or if mentioning that was simply Q attempting to appeal to Janeway and make her more amenable to the proposition.

Comment: @Xantec ... new pick up line for the bars? "I desire the addition of your human DNA, it's never been done before."

Comment: @NominSim: I see that line working very well *for* women, but not *on* women. ;)

Comment: @gnovice That is basically the plot of [Species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_(film))

Answer (score 6):

To pull a quote directly from [The Q and the Grey](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_and_the_Grey_%28episode%29):

> "Even if I wanted to mate, I wouldn't know how.  It's totally unprecedented." - **Q**
>
> "You'll figure something out.  You *are* omnipotent, after all." - **Janeway**
>
> "I need time to think about it." - **Q**

What has never been done before, was two Q having a child.  Amanda Rogers' parents did choose human form, and conceived her as humans.  And as we saw in [Deja Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deja_Q_%28episode%29), the Q have no difficulty in becoming human.

There's even a quote from Q in [True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/True_Q_%28episode%29) that supports this (emphasis mine):

> They had assumed human form, in order to visit Earth, I suppose.
> For..  for amusement.  But in *vulgar human fashion, they proceeded to
> conceive a child*.  And then like mawkish humans, they became attached
> to it.

This is further supported in the series of (non-canon) novels [The Q Continuum](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_Q_Continuum_%28novel_series%29), where the female Q from *The Q and the Grey* states that Amanda Rogers "doesn't count".

So no, the Q didn't forget about Amanda Rogers.  She just wasn't conceived of two Q.