# Where was Amanda Rogers during the Dominion War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q, star-trek-dominion

At the end of "True Q," Amanda Rogers uses her powers to reverse a catastrophe that would destroy all of Tagra IV. She says that she "couldn't let all those people die."

If Amanda was so concerned about the welfare of individuals living on Tagra IV, plus Geordi and maybe a few others from alien worlds, why didn't she do something to stop the Dominion War? Create instant peace between the Dominion and the Federation? Why not stop the Hirogen and the Borg when they attacked the Voyager, and also the Vidiians? And so on.

Comment: Very closely related: [Did Q forget about Amanda Rogers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17503) Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

By the time The Dominion War started, Amanda had been living as a Q for several Earth years. Although time & space are nearly meaningless to a Q, it's quite possible that by that time she had learned restraint - the equivalent of the Continuum's "Prime Directive" - and understood why events in the mortal universe must be allowed to play out without interference from the Q.

Stopping The Dominion War would have saved millions of lives in the short term, but who knows what effects it would have on the long-term timelines of the universe? The events of the war not only helped to unite the Federation, Klingons, and Romulans, it also introduced Odo to the true nature of his people and eventually provided an opportunity for long-term peace between them and solids.

Comment: This seems very speculative

Comment: @Richard Considering that this character is never mentioned again in cannon after the episode in which she initially appears, all answers must be speculative.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - It depends what you mean by "canon". She certainly appears in licensed properties such as various EU books.

Comment: this would seem a good answer based on purely tv/movie cannon, however richards answer seems to cover the books as well. but i had the same thought, that after a while of being a Q they imposed the same restrictions on her as they themselves follow, essentially they dont get involved that much.

Comment: @Himarm And there's some slight precedents (post-cedents?) with Q's son, Junior

Comment: I assumed she was just prevented from doing so by the other Q. They've done that before.

Answer (score 13):

### She never existed (see below).

Within the main trek canon (TV + Movies) there are no subsequent mentions of Amanda Rogers or her parents. In fact, the events of Voy : [Q and the Grey](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Q_and_the_Grey_(episode)) (where Q describes how there have been no new Q children since the beginning of the new era) would seem to completely ignore her existence.

This apparent contradiction is dealt with in the EU novel "[The Eternal Tide](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Eternal_Tide)". Amanda Rogers is investigating why Voyager and Captain Janeway appear to be doomed to destruction in multiple timelines. She encounters a powerful spatial rift and is unfortunately killed. Not only that, but her entire existence (including her entire timeline) is totally erased, with the Q known as Junior the only one who remembers her.

> *Releasing those fears and reminding herself of her limitless
>   abilities, Amanda moved closer to the emptiness. Only then did she
>   perceive its power over her. Why had she ever feared it? She belonged
>   to it, and it to her. It was her birthright. It was the most
>   magnificent, perfect energy that had ever existed. All that was Q
>   meant nothing in the face of this brilliance. It quietly demanded
>   surrender of all that she was, and with great eagerness she began to
>   pour herself into its insatiable need.*
>
> *It swallowed her whole.*

Q Junior is quite disappointed about this and spends much of the novel investigating the circumstances of her death before ultimately accepting that not only was it inevitable, but the result is that her entire existence has been erased:

> *“She died, trying to help me,” Q replied.
>
>   Icheb swallowed the lump that immediately formed in his throat at this revelation.
>   “I’m so sorry,” he said truthfully.
>
>   Q nodded. “Thank you.”
>
>   Icheb moved to sit next to Q on his rack. He had no idea how one might comfort a Q, but as he had appeared to him in human form, Icheb acted as if he were talking to a friend.
>
>   “I didn’t think the Q could die,” he said, hoping to draw Q out. It was clear that he needed to talk.
>
>   “They can, under very rare circumstances,” Q admitted.*

**If we take the book as a reliable source, then she was unable to intervene in the Dominion War because she never existed.**

Comment: So, what exactly is your answer? That she was preoccupied? I don't quite understand the point you might be making.

Comment: @fredsbend - If we take the book as a reliable source, then we learn that she's been totally erased from existence. This includes erasing her entire timeline. She never existed.

Comment: So the TNG episode introducing her also never existed. Makes sense now. I think you should make that a bit more clear in your answer.

Comment: @fredsbend - better? Feel free to make any edits that you think will make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, the last sentence is the definitive statement from what you had originally was lacking. +1