# In the E.T. Movie, or in the novels, is there an indication to an actual galaxy that's his fictional home?

Tags: star-wars, et-the-extra-terrestrial, george-lucas, steven-spielberg, real-location

In movies and sometimes books, an alien species on earth will point at a star or galaxy, if not outright name an actual galaxy they're from.  Is there a specific reference made in the movie or the two novelisations, including the sequel?

As such, it would help [canonically](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe) find the location of Star Wars' Galactic Republic.

Comment: @DampeS8N I don't think so.  The question seems to be about that universe referencing something that actually exists (like the [Andromeda Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_galaxy), for example)

Comment: Ooooohhhh... Home.....

Comment: An interpretation of the film is that ET is not an alien at all, it is a mixture of the children's imagination and possibly a real animal of some kind (most likely a dog). Before tearing my head off, have a look here: http://www.collativelearning.com/ET%20analysis.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no specific answer (that anyone's willing to give); however, it can be [conjectured](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Brodo_Asogi):

> In promotional material for E.T. the Extraterrestrial, it is stated that the little alien was "3,000,000 light years from home" when he was lost on Earth. Since galaxies such as our own Milky Way are only about 100,000 light years wide, he would in fact be an extragalactic being. A large galaxy, Triangulum is in the right distance to be E.T.'s home, meaning that Triangulum might actually be the Star Wars galaxy, a theory supported by the classification of Triangulum being a spiral, which is the galaxy type the Star Wars galaxy is typically considered to be. Additionally, the ship that appeared in E.T. looks quite similar to a Lucrehulk-class Core Ship, which may mean that the Trade Federation, Techno Union, or another wealthy financial power may have been key in financing Grebleips' expedition.

The Star Wars galaxy:
[image]

M33: Triangulum Galaxy:
[image]

Comment: Incidentally- if I have to accept my own answer, the bounty (and my rep) is lost by site rules.  I just wanted this answered.  Someone else please improve on this.