# Does "Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind" take place in the same universe as "Laputa: Castle in the Sky"?

Tags: nausicaa-of-the-valley-of-the-wind, laputa-castle-in-the-sky

Here is Teto, a creature known as a fox squirrel which Nausicaa befriends. He is often seen riding on her shoulder, in both the manga and the anime.

[image: Teto with Nausicaa]

In the anime *Laputa: Castle in the Sky* we also see what appears to be the exact same creature:

[image: Laputan Fox Squirrel, on a derelict robot]

Do the two stories occur in the same universe?

Comment: More likely just an easter egg. If you watch other Miyazki films there are plenty of them. For example in Kiki's Delivery Service a large red bus drives past the screen with the words "Studio Ghibli" written on the side, Totoro from My Neighbour Totoro appears in the background in multiple films as does Jiji the black cat from Kikis Delivery service. Miyazaki has a tendency to reuse character designs as a matter of expediency or economy due to the high cost of traditional cell animation. You can read list of Studio Ghibly easter eggs here... https://www.cbr.com/studio-ghibli-easter-eggs/

Comment: Do you know if the fox squirrel is a creature in traditional Japanese folklore?  Possibly They are as common in anime and manga as bigfoot in USA cartoons.

Comment: @skyjack Absolutely! And don't get me started on the [soot spirits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susuwatari)! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From reading several articles across the internet I would have to say this is a fan theory only and not borne out in any direct quote from Studio Ghibli or Miyazaki himself.

[This article](https://ap2hyc.com/2021/01/are-the-studio-ghibli-films-set-in-the-same-universe/) directly addresses whether multiple Studio Ghibli films are set in the same universe or narrative and conclude this is not the case:

> There is no concrete evidence that all the films exist in the same world, though minor characters do cross over.

Having visited the Studio Ghibli Museum in Tokyo and having seen some of Miyazki's notes on exhibited story boards for Spirited Away where he notes that the background female faces in one scene can all be basically the same to keep down production costs, it is clear he is a pragmatic film maker. The appearance of Teto in Laputa is an easter egg and nothing more. If you look closely at his other character designs, Muska from Laputa bears a resemblance to the father in Totoro. The Laputa robots have their design origins in Lupin the Third made 18 (?) years before Laputa. Meanwhile the makkuro kurosuke from Totoro reoccur in Spirited Away. It is too much to ask that all these films make up one mega-text.

For the sake of completeness the following links are the other articles I consulted.

- https://yattatachi.com/studio-ghibli-animation-easter-eggs
- https://www.cbr.com/studio-ghibli-easter-eggs/
- http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/miyazaki_hayao
- http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/kaze_no_tani_no_nausicaa
- http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/tenku_no_shiro_rapyuta
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Hayao_Miyazaki

Comment: Yet the appearances of ET in _Star Wars_ and R2-D2 in _Indiana Jones_, which could be classified as easter eggs as well, is enough to most to claim it to be the same universe.

Comment: lucas has confirmed a shared universe between star wars and et see this answer for details https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe but sometimes an easter egg is just an easter egg