# What was the thermal exhaust port on the first Death Star venting?

Tags: star-wars

This came up [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8559/3804), and it seems like it required another question.

> I always assumed that the Torpedoes were 'sucked' in. Although thinking about it, the port is an exhaust port. Perhaps some complex pump system causes a pressure differential after exhausting waste gas.

Our candidates are: Heat, Gas, Solid, Liquid, Plasma.

What was the vent venting?

Comment: The weekly curry night was just before, and you know how it gets ....

Comment: Venting heat would be unlikely, since that would be handled with heatsinks.

Comment: @TangoOversway - To say nothing of the fact that the vacuum of space doesn't conduct heat. Unless the heat it's venting is radiant (like sunlight), this vent can't be of any use at all, as there are no atoms to convey heat energy in space.

Comment: I think a better way to word the question would be, "How does a hole or port vent heat instead of a heat sink?"  There's nothing there, just a hole.  It's not possible to vent heat that way.

Comment: My guess is that it's for radiating heat and GL didn't know how inefficient that is.

Comment: Considering the port is "ray shielded" (assuming that means electro-magnetic) then it probably isn't be radiative.

Comment: @TangoOversway Heatsinks don't vent heat.  They store heat while a fan cools off the heatsink, so a vent of some sort is still needed.  Which means gas, liquid, etc is still needed.

Comment: @Izkata: Yeah, I was thinking of only part of the process.  My bad.

Comment: It wasn't an exhaust port, it was an [aesthetic choice by the architect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcL6DwSufMI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Radioactive particles

The issues that the exhaust port was intended to deal with are discussed in great detail in the *Rogue One* novelization. Basically, radioactive particles from the reactor core were causing it to overheat.

> I also spoke to my team and we identified the problem. The reactor
>   core modifications are resulting in radiation buildup, which in turn
>   has the potential of interfering with the hypermatter annihilator.
>
> **The buildup is caused by the inner shield actively reflecting excess
>   particles and metaphorically “cooking” the reactor core.** Had the
>   shielding team’s research not been so heavily compartmentalized this
>   might have been avoided.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

The exhaust port was one of three proposed methods for dealing with the aforementioned problems.

> Option three: construction of manual venting shafts and **thermal
>   exhaust ports. This should reduce particle buildup to within
>   tolerances** but not to a degree I find personally acceptable. In
>   addition, adding venting shafts risks additional incompatibilities
>   with noncritical systems.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

It’s probably worth noting that expelling massive radioactive particles would really be the only feasible way of reducing heat buildup in the core. Radiative heat loss (i.e. from electromagnetic radiation, which is to say massless particles) in space is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that it vents heat by expelling superheated gases (not plasma). Everyone is right that the only way heat can escape a body in space is by radiation, so an "exhaust port" designed to expel pure heat the way a car's exhaust would wouldn't work very well.

HOWEVER, that's not the only way to remove heat while in a vacuum. A very effective way to cool heated surfaces such as heatsinks is to spray a liquid onto that surface, forcing conduction of the heat away from said surface, and then expelling the now-heated liquid or gas into the void. As the main source of heat in the Death Star would be its reactor core, should that core overheat, you can cool the entire system by simply expelling some of the coolant and replenishing it.

The original novel by Lucas states, as an extension to the dialogue heard in the movie, something along the lines of "the shaft would be rendered useless by particle shielding; however, it is completely ray-shielded". This further increases my confidence that the "thermal exhaust" consists primarily of matter and not energy. And, we know there's a main port that usually handles most of the station's cooling needs, but this port can likely be particle-shielded to protect it in an attack, leaving the auxiliary port to handle the cooling needs.

Comment: That last sentence is the clincher!

Answer (score 5):

Surely the fact that it's a *thermal* exhaust port indicates that it vents heat?

[Thermal exhaust port](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thermal_exhaust_port)

Comment: But through what medium?

Comment: Exactly!  Heat isn't just vented, it has to pass through matter.  That's what a heat sink is for.

Comment: @TangoOversway - Slightly misleading statement, heat can pass through vacuum in the form of radiated light - witness the sun. A heat-sink whilst usually designed to remove most of its heat by convection, some will radiate too.  That said, I understand what you mean - either this port radiates very little heat, or it would have to be glowing.

Comment: @iandotkelly, maybe it does glow! It just wasn't venting at the time we see it one screen.

Comment: @iandotkelly - it would have to be glowing the same way laser shots in vacuum have to be silent.

Comment: @DVK - yes, perhaps physics works differently in this universe

Comment: @iandotkelly: Maybe it *was* glowing, but in a non-visible portion of the EM spectrum (i.e. infrared).

Comment: @iandotkelly it is [our universe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/has-the-star-wars-universe-caught-up-to-our-time)

Comment: You'd need to heat an object up to a couple thousand degrees (Celsius) before it would start noticeably glowing; on the other hand, space is -270 degrees. That's a pretty large temperature range in which radiative heat transfer would be (somewhat) effective. Alternatively, the port could be dissipating heat by [evaporative cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler).

Comment: Things start glowing at around 400 Celsius, not 'couple thousand', so this would be ~670 Kelvin as the upper bound on the difference between the vent and space, which actually isn't that large a temperature difference.  Evaporative cooling in the context of a vacuum means dumping a material into space.  As @anthony-arnold points out - one explanation is that it wasn't venting at the time of the attack.

Comment: @Pureferret: Through some form of vaporized matter that the station has in sufficient supply that it can afford to jettison it.  Note that even though the port would be venting material rather than heat, that wouldn't imply that the purpose of the port was to jettison coolant.  BTW, if the jettisoned material was strongly charged (implying that jettisoning it would give the station the opposite charge) I wonder whether it might be possible for the station to recover the material without regaining all the kinetic energy it had contained?