# Is "My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic" canon with Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-q, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

Inspired by the [various](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/has-the-light-from-the-star-wars-galaxy-reached-us-yet/3007#3007) [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/has-the-star-wars-universe-caught-up-to-our-time/6331#6331) and [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe) about ET and Star Wars based on a cameo, I wanted to know is Star Trek and My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic in the same Multiverse?

Now before you go laughing me off of the internet I recommend you watch the following video.

[image: Youtube click image]

For those who are not familiar with the show, the dragon character is named [Discord](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Discord), and he is the embodiment of chaos. He can teleport, alter reality (sometimes by snapping his fingers), has fondness for games, and is voiced by John de Lancie.

We all know crossing between dimensions is within Q's powers, and he didn't always use the same name or human form. Could Q travel to a universe that has sentient talking ponies with magic powers? And if so, does that make My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic canon? (If ET's cameo makes him canon to Star Wars, I think this should make MLP canon with Star Trek.)

Comment: haha... kudos for the clever question.  Of course, when we start talking about omnipotent/cross-dimensional beings existing in multiple universes as evidence of a cross-over between stories, then almost anything can be considered part of anything else's canon.

Comment: Seems to be more of a nod to the character Q than anything else, though I can't imagine viewers of My Little Pony getting it...

Comment: @Paperjam Considering how many My Little Pony fans are actually males between the ages of 18-30, there's definitely some viewers who will get it.

Comment: @Flimzy Well, considering that at least 180 shows are all connected to St. Elsewhere, which only exists in an autistic child's mind... http://home.vicnet.net.au/~kwgow/crossovers.html

Comment: A) What is wrong with people? B) How did people make the connection to MLP and Star Trek, when if ANYTHING should be a crossover by this logic, it would be Gargoyles?

Comment: MLP is canon with multiple universes. "The Big Lebowski", the ancient Greek mythology, Star Wars (with Jedi Zecora), and possibly the X-Men universe in S4.

Comment: Up next in questions from Scott Chamberlain: *Is [YHWH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahweh) really Q in canon?* ;)

Comment: Ah, Nov 4th 2011. The precise moment in history when all the obvious *Star Trek* questions had already been asked and we started on the other sort.

Comment: I can't believe I wasted 5 minutes on this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Not Canonically**. While the canon policy of Star Trek is vague, and the best I can find of it is on wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon) or on the wayback machine from the official site [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100427065410/http://www.startrek.com/startrek/view/help/faqs/faq/676.html), it is still clear that media which isn't branded Star Trek is out since even media which is isn't necessarily in. Given what we know about Q, it is certainly conceivable that Q and discord are the same being; however, that doesn't require it in any way.

Answer (score 14):

Obviously as already stated by sebsmith in his answer, the two medias cannot be considered canon to each other. We are talking about two different shows, with intellectual property rights owned by two separate entities. Unless some sort of agreement was made, it would be impossible for either of the shows to incorporate elements of the other in its canon.

That said, I would like to add something no one else has pointed out. That actually there have been multiple references in the MLP to Star Trek.

The most evident one is found in the main comic, issue #16. Here the mane six travel through different stories while trying to trap a magical creature on the loose. One of the stories places them aboard a very familiar starship...

[image]

... And some time after, Friends Forever #2 managed to do ever better than that. The CMC were still trying to earn their cutie mark and after meeting Discord in the Sweet Apple Orchard they decide to ask him for help, hoping that the spirit of chaos may think up something new "they never would have thought of".
This prompts Discord to create some sort of pocket dimension and make the CMC (who were initially bored by some of his initial proposals, such as lion tamers or fire fighters) go through an increasingly weirder sequence of alternate realities featuring things like The Lord of The Rings, 80's style cops shows, and the following...

[image]
(it is somehow unclear if all of those should be considered as realities that Discord created based on info he got somewhere else or should be regarded as alternate realities such as those from the Reflection story arc)

As already stated, both references don't really prove anything and should be considered nothing more than a little nod to Star Trek fans, but it is still nice to know that Discord actually has already crossed the fourth wall at least once to point at his Q "alter-ego".

Comment: Was Discord a member of the crew in that last comic, or some annoying godlike visitor who popped in to stir up trouble?

Comment: @amarillo Discord was dressed in [the traditional formal garb of the Q](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-Arrival-Custom-Made-Star-Trek-The-next-generation-Q-s-judge-robe-costume-Cosplay/1022001619.html).

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - Just a little nitpick (as Star Trek fans love to do), but that outfit wasn't actually traditional to the Q, it was just what Q wore when he was playing the role of a judge in a 21st century court (after going through some other costumes from Earth's history earlier in the episode). And I think amarillo was asking about how Discord's costume was explained in the context of the comic, if at all (though his "hmmm...this one seems familar" kind of suggests it might have been a one-panel joke during some kind of sequence where they were jumping through different settings)

Comment: @amarillo edited the answer to add some context info for the second reference. If you want me to expand on some other details, fell free to ask.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yep, it was some sort of jumping thru settings sequence, with the only interesting factor begin that Discord was controlling the whole jumping so you could at least say he didn't end up there "by chance". As already stated, probably he was aiming at trolling *the readers* ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer here would require more understanding about Q, but I do not see that it would be outside his powers to cross himself to a parallel but fundamentally disconnected reality, being the MLP reality. He may well be differently constrained there, and has to appear as a dragon, or it may be his choice. Or it may be a Q who found himself caught in this universe and could not return.

Whatever, even if Discord is a Q, if there is no connection from the MLP universe as it is now, and the Trek universe - and there has been nothing in either series as far as I am aware that would suggest continuing crossover - then there is no canon implications. The fact that beings who may be related exist in two universes BUT DO NOT INTERACT WITH EACH OTHER should not imply canonicity, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't Q say he was a god (or at least the trickster spirit as in Native American mythology) for several planets?
I think that Q could easily have claimed to be that sort of thing for a planet of polychromic ponies.
And like you said, if that is the case, then starships could come to Equestria.

Comment: Maybe Q was lying when he said that.