# How many times did Picard tell Wesley to shut up?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, Captain Picard was often seen telling young upstart Wesley Crusher to shut up. How often did this happen, and furthermore, when did it happen first? [image]

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know, but I think the first time was in "Datalore", when Wesley first realized that Lore was impersonating Data. I can't think of another time as it was out of character for Picard to say it at all. One of my least favorite episodes BTW, for that reason.

Comment: Not nearly enough times.

Comment: @childofsoong: clicked on this "hot network question" mostly to make the same joke.  Although really I liked the character, and don't mean that.

Comment: Not the same thing exactly, [but relevant](http://hijinksensue.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/2013-04-17-make-it-so-as-you-wish.jpg)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Once

There are only four times when someone told Wesley to "shut up" on *TNG*, and two of them are the same.

- ***Datalore (1x13)***

  Twice, by two different people

  > PICARD: Shut up, Wesley. (turning) Lieutenant Yar, pick a good security
  >   team, let me know what he does.

  and

  > WESLEY: Since I am finished here, Captain, may I point out... ?
  >
  > BEVERLY: Shut up, Wesley!
- ***The Dauphin (2x10)***:

  > WESLEY: I don't think this is my style.
  >
  > GUINAN: Shut up, kid. (to Riker, dreamily) Now tell me more about my
  >   eyes.
- ***Shades of Grey (2x22)***:

  > WESLEY: I don't think this is my style.
  >
  > GUINAN: Shut up, kid. (to Riker, dreamily) Now tell me more about my
  >   eyes.

Yes, the last two are the same. There was a writers' strike going on at the time of *Shades of Grey*, and the episode had to be [produced quickly and on a low budget](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/star-trek-the-next-generation-shades-of-grey-43316).

> ...the low-budget nature of the episode **means we barely see anyone
>   outside of flashbacks**: there's Picard, Geordi, Data, Pulaski, Troi,
>   and Riker, and an extra or two.

### Only one of these times is Picard; ironic for such an iconic phrase.

<sub><sup>I searched all the scripts [here](http://antoa.com/tng/) to confirm that these are the only cases</sup></sub>

Comment: @Dpeif - Yes. Yes they are. "Because of the 1988 Writers Guild of America strike they had to shoot this episode in 3 days. It's pretty much crap, **consisting of repeat cut + pasted clips from Season 2** and was described by its writer, Maurice Hurley as 'terrible, just terrible.' "

Comment: It’s too bad they didn’t air a My Little Pony episode during the writers’ strike. That would have lent weight to [this theory](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/is-my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic-canon-with-star-trek). (original MLP)

Comment: The quotes from the Dauphin and Shades of Grey are identical in your answer...

Comment: @iMerchant - "Because of the 1988 Writers Guild of America strike they had to shoot this episode in 3 days. It's pretty much crap, consisting of repeat cut + pasted clips from Season 2 and was described by its writer, Maurice Hurley as 'terrible, just terrible.' " –

Comment: @anaranjada - Yeah, I'm planning to given that I needed to say it twice.

Comment: @Jonah - Ironic your comment was cut & pasted just like the two episodes in question. Lol

Comment: Why did Bev tell Wesley to shut up? That's pure comedy :')

Comment: In-universe, are the two exchanges between Wesley and Guinan actually two distinct occurrences, or a single occurrence that appears on screen twice (e.g. in a flashback)?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: The latter. Riker is in some kind of a coma and relives previous events in his mind.

Comment: Ah well, I guess it could be worse... there could have been multiple writers strikes, each one producing a Shades of Gray like episode, the final one being a rehash of all the other rehashes.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 It was because Wesley didn't shut up when Picard told him to. She was trying to stop him from digging himself deeper into the hole.