# What's the name of the galaxy far, far away?

Tags: star-wars

Has the in-universe name of the Star Wars galaxy ever mentioned in the canon?

Comment: Presumably not [Ford](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/quotes?item=qt0467058).

Comment: I was just about to post the same question..

Comment: Bob.  Its name is Bob.

Comment: They misspelled it in the opening blurb. The galaxy is actually called Agalaxyfarfaraway.

Comment: Can we be 100% certain that it's not *our* galaxy?  After all, we don't know where or when the narrator is.  Someone in the distant future and in another galaxy could be reviewing what happened at a time that in relation to us would be considered our future.

Comment: The Doctor once named a galaxy Alison. It could be that.

Comment: @Chahk We know about several galaxies near the Star Wars galaxy, and they do not resemble the galaxies near us.  The Star Wars galaxy also appears to be un-barred spiral while the Milky Way is a barred spiral.  So no, it's not the Milky Way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Canon**: No. This has never been addressed.

**Legends**: Only [Star Wars: The Essential Atlas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Atlas) has any mention of the name of the galaxy, and even then only notes that [the Nagai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nagai) refer to the galaxy by the name **Skyriver**.

In addition to the lack of name, there is also no indication in any level of canon to just how far away Skyriver might be.

Comment: How far away?  Crossover-canon (if there is such a thing) [has an answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/has-the-light-from-the-star-wars-galaxy-reached-us-yet?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah, I considered mentioning that, but there is really NO evidence that those are the same species as ET. The fact that a child is dressed as Yoda in ET makes any argument for that idea even weaker, IMO.

Comment: *"..no indication in any level of canon to just how far away Skyriver might be."*  Further than far away, but closer than far, far, far away. ;)

Comment: Skyriver? I just prefer it remain unnamed in that case. Lucas finally made a good choice and kept his mouth shut.

Comment: @iMerchant - Yeah, because Milky Way is soooo much classier.

Comment: It’s probably just Alpha-Centauri to us. ;) Basically our next door neighbor galaxy.