# Is the Star Wars Universe just one galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, canon

At the start of the movie it says:

> **"A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...."**

Does this mean that the entire Star Wars saga takes place in a single galaxy?
To my understanding a galaxy isn't very big compared to the universe itself. Star Wars has many different sentient races, and the way they are presented suggests that most planets are host to only one of them (some exceptions like naboo). This strongly leads me to believe there should actually be more galaxies in the Star Wars universe (hehe).

Another thing, I think it's safe to assume that even if the entire saga takes place in one single galaxy, their researchers can observe other galaxies (I think we started doing that in the 1600s, and they are a lot more technologically advanced than we were back then). When Obi-wan is looking for Kamino (the rain planet with the cloners) the librarian says something like "If it's not in our records, it doesn't exist", so she must be convinced that the entire universe has been explored.

If the entire universe has been documented, why wouldn't they go to those other galaxies? The technology seems to be advanced enough to hop to another galaxy. Is there any canon material that suggest that traveling between galaxies is done? If not, is there a canon explanation why they don't?

Comment: **<comments removed>** Take the tangential discussion to chat please.

Comment: Well, an earth librarian doesn't necessarily know as much about the state of discovery of our galaxy as NASA does. She can be convinced of all sorts of stuff, but she ain't the one launching exploratory missions.

Comment: “Just”? Man, some people are never happy.

Comment: The formal name of the Empire is the _Galactic_ Empire.  If it occupied more than one galaxy, they'd call it something else, like the Universal Empire.  Otherwise it'd be like calling the US the "Continental Republic".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Based on the maps seen in Star Wars II and III, the action takes place in a single galaxy but there are also several "dwarf galaxies" in orbit of the main galaxy.

**Star Wars II**
[image]

We also have confirmation from the narrator of *[*Star Wars: Empire Strikes Back - So You Want To Be A Jedi?*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)* that there are indeed other galaxies, presumably including our own.

> All I’m trying to say is that “gross” is a matter of opinion. **In some
> galaxies, eating kidneys is gross. In other galaxies, swimming pools
> are.**

There's also repeated mention of an "*Intergalactic Banking Clan*" that plies its trade between the main galaxy and [its satellite galaxies](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rishi_Maze) (including the Rishi Maze), so clearly leaving the main galaxy to go beyond the Outer Rim isn't a huge deal, as long as you're not heading out into the void.

---

Moving down the canon scale, there's mention of a vague threat from intergalactic barbarians in the *[Revenge of the Sith: Incredible Cross-Sections](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_Incredible_Cross-Sections)* factbook:

> The Imperial Starfleet will justify its existence in unending war
> against Separatist holdouts, dissident rebels and even, it is rumored,
> deterring **barbarian invaders from outside the galaxy**.

And in [various EU novels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Intergalactic_Void) it's explained that the Yuuzhan Vong had to cross from their galaxy to the Skyriver Galaxy at **sublight** speed due the 'inability of the hyperdrive system to lock onto recognisable features', which would explain the general lack of true intergalactic travel

Comment: There *is* an in-universe name for the Star Wars galaxy [mentioned in former C-Canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35637/whats-the-name-of-the-galaxy-far-far-away).

Comment: @Phantom42 - Skyriver is more of a description than a name. I take your point though.

Comment: Yuuzhan Vong were supposedly in world ships, that took thousands of years to cross through space between the 2 galaxies.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought travel from one galaxy to another wasn't possible because there were no known safe hyperspace routes. In the video game, *Knights of the Old Republic*, one of the main characters, a Mandolorian named Canderous, describes how he and his crew chased a Vong scout to the edge of the galaxy. They stopped at the edge of the galaxy because they believed chasing the scout beyond the galaxy would be the equivalent of committing suicide.

Comment: @jliv902 - In the EU canon, it's mentioned that you can't get a hyperspace lock in the void. There's nothing to stop you just pointing your ship toward the nearest galaxy and turning on your engines though.

Comment: @Richard, Skyriver is a description the same way Milky Way is, don't you think?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - I don't disagree. That said, it could just be **one** species' name for it rather than a general appellation.

Comment: @Richard, lights takes time to reach places, you can't just point your ship at a galaxy, it may not be even there in the first place

Comment: @svarog - If your plan is to rely on point'n'shoot navigation, you'd better be bloody fast.

Answer (score 17):

The story takes place "In **a** galaxy far, far away" - that is, in one galaxy, that doesn't include ours, so not the entire universe. So yes, "just" one galaxy.

Being able to see other galaxies is very different from being able to travel to them.

Check out the math of how many stars are in one galaxy (hundreds of billions), and how many galaxies we think are in our known universe. From your question, it doesn't seem like you appreciate the enormity of a single galaxy, let alone the universe. All the Star Wars stories AND fan fiction could probably fit in one millionth of one galaxy, or less. Galaxies are also almost always at extreme distances from each other. The ability to jump from one solar system to another is extremely small compared to the ability to travel across one single galaxy, which itself would be extremely small compared to the ability to jump to another galaxy, unless your technology makes distance irrelevant. Listening to Han Solo talk about travel times in the first film, it sounds like distance is a consideration even to familiar planets.

Even if travel could be done instantly, imagine the time and effort required to gather information about 100 billion stars. Just try counting to a billion, and let us know how far you get before you stop, and how long that took. Hint: One billion seconds is over 30 years.

"When Obi-wan is looking for Kamino (the rain planet with the cloners) the librarian says something like "If it's not in our records, it doesn't exist", so she must be convinced that the entire universe has been explored." 
- No, I am certain she means simply that any planet of any interest to Obi Wan would surely be in her records, not that there aren't planets outside the known galaxy. And of course, she's wrong about even this statement.

Comment: I don't think you can apply real-world astronomy facts regarding galactic scales to a scifi universe which is as scientifically soft as Star Wars. [Sci-Fi writers have no sense of scale](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScifiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale), after all.

Answer (score 10):

I am surprised that no one has yet mentioned the rendezvous point at the end of The Empire Strikes Back.

[image: Looking at the galaxy from afar]

The characters are looking at the galaxy from far outside it, and there are also stars in all directions in all the shots, meaning the rendezvous point is in another galaxy, at least a separate satellite galaxy or star cluster.

Comment: It certainly _looks_ like what we generally think a galaxy looks like, but it could (must?) be something else.  If I had to make something up, I'd probably say it's a protostar.

Comment: [It has been confirmed to be the Star Wars galaxy.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/where-was-the-rebel-fleets-rendezvous-point-at-the-end-of-the-empire-strikes-ba)

Comment: Furthermore, when the movie came out in 1980, nobody thought protoplanetary disks or indeed anything but galaxies looked like that. Protoplanetary disks shouldn't have a central bulge. Certainly nobody had seen any by 1980, but every artist's conception lacks a bulge. And finally, the characters stare at it rather meaningfully and the Millennium Falcon flies toward it in the scene. These actions make no sense unless it is the Star Wars galaxy.

Comment: That's *a* galaxy. What if it's not the galaxy the story is set in? The Andromeda galaxy looks to be about that big from our vantage point here on earth - *if* you could amplify the light enough to make it this bright. Based on the scale we see here, that puts the galaxy in the background at around 2 million light years away, well outside the galaxy they're currently occupying, which would typically be about 100-200 thousand light years across. Just because the Millenium Falcon is flying towards it, doesn't mean that there aren't a hundred million stars between this place and that galaxy.

Comment: I still believe that the end of EpV shows that people in the Star Wars Universe can travel outside the galaxy, but I'm not sure that the rebels are anywhere significant outside the galaxy, because the shots of the fleet don't show any surrounding planets/stars.

Comment: @Gandalf'sFISTS What do you mean, they don't show any surrounding planets/stars? Look at the picture in the answer. Do you see the stars to C3PO's left and Leia's right in the picture above? They are everywhere in all the exterior shots. I'll add more pictures to the answer later if you still need them.

Comment: @JDoe yes, but the stars all look like they do from Earth, meaning that the closest stars are at least lightyears away, and that's assuming they are actually stars and not galaxies, which many of them could be

Comment: @Gandalf'sFISTS Galaxies aren't bright enough to look like that. From Earth the only galaxies we can see are Andromeda and the two Magellanic clouds, which look like faint blobs. No galaxy far enough away to appear point-like would be bright enough to be visible to the naked eye. Those must be stars, and they must be in a nearby star cluster or satellite galaxy like the Magellanic clouds to be surrounded by them.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

If you take the fact that E.T. came to Earth in the movie *E.T. he Extra-terrestrial* and then you take a closer look at these aliens in the Republic Senate in *The Phantom Menace*.

I think it is safe to say that some aliens on the Star Wars galaxy are able to travel in other galaxies counting our own Milky Way.

Comment: This is an easter-egg put in by George Lucas after Steven Spielberg created a Yoda easter-egg appearance in E.T. (they did a lot of this stuff in their movies and even had a drawing contest, drawing movie posters for each other's movies)

Comment: still.. the E.T. race is in both galaxies

Comment: No there are space creatures that look like E.T. in the senate. There is no confirmation at all that this is the same species as E.T. In fact, I don't think it's known what E.T.'s species is called or where they are from, nor is it known what these creatures in the senate are called and where they are from.

Comment: lets call them "the twins" !

Comment: @Kevin E.T recognises Yoda in *E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial*, indicating that these species do exist in the same galaxy (and as such, these films are set in the same universe).

Comment: @DrRDizzle Just the fact that Spielberg put a reference to Yoda in his movie, doesn't mean that the Star Wars lore is somehow affected by that. They are two completely different movies, that have nothing to do with each other and are made by different studios.

Comment: @Kevin And yet both films support the theory that *E.T: The Extra-Terrestrial* and the Star Wars films are set in the same universe. It's also worth noting that Steven Spielberg directed part of *Star Wars Episode III: The Revenge of the Sith*.

Comment: @Kevin Also - they are called [Asogians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Asogian), and they come from [Brodo Asogi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Brodo_Asogi). One of the ones pictured here is called [Grebleips](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grebleips), which is "Spielberg" backwards. They actually have a fair bit of history and lore in the Star Wars Extended Universe.

Answer (score 1):

There are as @Dronz pointed out trillions of stars in most Galaxies. That surely answers your question about the number of known races vs the number of planets. In the linked wiki page at the bottom, the intergalactic invaders known as the Yuuzhan Vong are described.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong

A summary of the Vong are a warlike species of nature lovers essentially. They crossed from the nearest major galaxy after decimating their own in a war and invaded the tech based New Republic during an economic depression and time of war, conquering corusant.

Comment: A galaxy with a trillion stars is unusually large. It's probably accurate to say that most galaxies have tens or hundreds of billions of stars, which is more than enough to support the variety of species we see in Star Wars.

Answer (score -2):

The place mentioned in Attack of the Clones Obi Wan is looking for Jango, the Rishi Maze, is a smaller satellite galaxy (as seen on the image from the movie) and it's the closest of 3 sat galaxies, somewhat closer than the 2nd closest which is approximately 150 million LYs away from the main galaxy.  Kamino is apparently just outside this sat galaxy, and Obi Wan is able to travel to and through the Rishi Maze and back with relative ease.  It sounds like the 2nd sat galaxy (known as Firefist) is at least partially explored. The 3rd doesn't seem to be explored or named at present.  It is possible the fleet at the end of ESB is in or near one of the sat galaxies looking back at the main one.  This is all on Wookieepedia, by the way.

Comment: This could really use specific supporting evidence.

Comment: The planet (Kamino) where Kenobi found Jango Fett was part of a system inside the galaxy where all the rest of the action takes place. Unless you have some proof that the Rishi Maze is another galaxy, I will go on believing that it is a star cluster inside the original galaxy.

Comment: For those wanting exact reference (and not willing to look at the Wookieepedia article source bibliographies), here you go.

Comment: Dwarf satellite galaxies named Companion A (Rishi Maze), Companion B (Firefist), and Companion C exist based on the Star Wars Essential Atlas (2009) , also supported in the SW RPG supplement The Unknown Regions (2010), and SW Insider articles in issues 80 and 131.  Not to forget that nearby dwarf galaxies certainly exist based on the onscreen map from Attack of the Clones and the final shots from Empire Strikes Back (as others have already pointed out.)

Comment: Possibly the best evidence was from Leland Chee who confirmed on Star wars.com that the Rishi Maze is a separate galaxy.  Chee was Lucasfilm's canon archivist, and under Disney is in charge of streamlining a cohesive continuity for the new canon of the SW universe.  Considering that most non-film events from pre-Disney have been declared non-canon, but that most alien species and locations from those sources seem to be retained (especially those that were made up or confirmed directly by Disney's  SW continuity director), I would assume this is canon unless directly contradicted in the future.