# Why aren't there any nebulae in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, space

In *Star Trek* there are nebulae practically everywhere. I don't remember seeing any in *Star Wars* though, why is that?

[image]

### Why does *Star Trek* hog all the nebulae and *Star Wars* has none?

---

If there actually is some obscure nebula in the Star Wars universe, the question remains - Why does *Star Trek* have so many while *Star Wars* has (next to) none? I don't know enough to say which portrayal is more accurate. Have the makers of either franchise commented on the prominence/absence of nebulae? If no such official commentary exists, I welcome speculation.

Comment: Space is big. Really big. We don’t see that much of it in *Star Wars*, so I guess the camera just wasn’t pointing at any nebulae.

Comment: Star Trek has unrealistically impressive nebula, Star Wars has unrealistically impressive asteroid fields.  I'm going to call it a tie. :-)

Comment: In Star Trek they are actively exploring and looking for interesting phenomena. In Star Wars that fact that space is involved at all is secondary to the plot.

Comment: Compare [What are the effects of a planet staying long-term inside of a nebula?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/14499/29) on [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: I believe there was an episode of the clone wars animated series that featured a nebula.

Comment: Star Trek takes place in our galaxy. Star Wars is in another. Apparently, the other galaxy doesn't have as many nebulae.

Comment: Nebula in real-life aren't colorful like in Star Trek, in any case... They are re-colored images.

Comment: @AndresF. Most photos we have of nebula are just several grayscale images from different frequencies stitched together as the red, green, blue and alpha channels of the image. Displaying them as a normal image looks cool but is very unrealistic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: FWIW, I *think* they really would be (relatively) colourful if our eyes could see colour at the dim light intensities involved.

Comment: That's a superbly misleading graphic. You've just cherry-picked examples to support your argument, but it's a completely biased representation. There have been _hundreds_ of episodes of Star Trek in which no nebulae were seen. How many "episodes" of Star Wars have there been in which no nebulae were seen?

Comment: @MrLister Right. Star Wars takes place long, long, ago, so the nebulae just haven't formed yet :)

Comment: Lucas probably didn't know what nebulae were.  Not like he had Wikipedia.

Answer (score 70):

Star Trek does not represent nebulae at all accurately.  [Real nebulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula) are nowhere near that dense - they'd constitute a hard vacuum by our standards.  They're also big, typically hundreds of light-years across.

As far as I know, there's no canon reason why any of the scenes in Star Wars *couldn't* have been set near planets that are located inside a nebula, but also no particular reason why they should.  But while nebulae look pretty from a distance, the only thing you'd notice from inside them was that you couldn't see as many stars.  (Perhaps the ones you could see would be a bit fuzzy; I'm not sure.)  Basically it just wouldn't make for a pretty picture.

(It might be reasonable to guess that a nebula would interfere with hyperdrive travel, in which case planets within one would likely remain uncolonized.)

Comment: Compare [What are the effects of a planet staying long-term inside of a nebula?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/14499/29) on [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: Also, do remember that most of the colorful pictures we get from NASA are stylized and incorporate representations of frequencies outside of the visible spectrum (ie infrared and ultraviolet).

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay its not so much "outside the visible spectrum."  The Hubble images are all visible spectrum - just that they've remapped the colors.  [Are Hubble Telescope Images in true color?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197487/20936) describes this.

Comment: Wasn't there a scene in the Joiner King where Han and Leia are flying out of control into a nebula? I remember Han makes some witty remark asking Leia if she could use the force to part it much like she had done earlier with some storm clouds.

Comment: @GheyPhistor: I think the OP was thinking of the movies in particular, but [NKCampbell's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/119865/5930) already covers a few non-movie canon examples.

Comment: @KellyThomas I am quite familiar with it (check the answers in the post that I linked).  http://www.almadenobservatory.net/Color_Imagery.html along with http://hubblesite.org/gallery/behind_the_pictures/meaning_of_color/eagle.php are also good reads.  While Hubble can get into the IR range (http://hubblesite.org/gallery/behind_the_pictures/meaning_of_color/saturn.php) it tends to be in the visible spectrum.  Sometimes there have been composite images with the Chandra observatory - http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2010/snr0509/ to do the X-ray data.

Answer (score 30):

Most of the shots within Star Wars are taken next to planets. Whereas far more action within Star Trek happens in deep space.

Nebulas do not tend to appear next to planets, or within planetary systems, they do happen in deep space however.

It is merely due to the settings. Star Wars has a higher percentage of asteroid fields due to this same planetary system setting.

Comment: *Nebulas do not tend to appear next to planets* - true, I suppose, in much the same way that you don't often find a continent inside your house. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I did however find a continent *next* to my house once...

Comment: @Michael: true, the real problem with talking about a nebula being next to a planet isn't the size so much as the fuzzy edges.  But I couldn't think of an analogy for that. :-)

Answer (score 24):

Just to outline the current canon uses

**Disney canon:**

**Rebels: Season 2: Ep 12** - Legends of the Lasat depicts an impenetrable space cloud / nebula

Pictured here:
[image]

**Clone Wars: Season 1: Ep 3** - Shadow of Malevolence depicts the Kalidda Nebula

Pictured here:

[image]

**Tarkin** (novel)

Tarkin recalls a lesson taught to him when he was a young man

> You make use of asteroid fields, nebulae, star flares, whatever you
>   find, to intensify the havoc

Wookieepedia also indicates minor references to nebula in the books *Lords of the Sith*, *Lost Stars*, *Aftermath*, and new canon comics.

Answer (score 10):

An out of universe explanation for why nebulas show up so often in Star Trek is because they had the effect already done and kept reusing it to save money and add some visual variety.  Starfields and planets are cheap, but they get dull after a while.

Star Trek II: The Wrath Of Khan ends with the [Battle of the Mutara Nebula](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Mutara_Nebula), a striking purple and blue hued nebula rippling with electricity.

[image: The Mutara Nebula]

The relatively big budget of a movie, as compared to a TV show (Wrath Of Khan was fairly cheap), allowed more spectacular practical effects.  Always ones to shave costs where they can, this effect got reused again and again by the TV shows.

First the Mutara Nebula was recycled in TNG as the [Paulson Nebula](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paulson_Nebula) where the Enterprise-D hid from the Borg in ["The Best Of Both Worlds"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds_%28episode%29).

[image: Paulson Nebula]

In the DS9 episode ["Vortex"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vortex_(episode)) it becomes the [Chamra Vortex](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chamra_Vortex).

[image: Chamra Vortex]

An altered version became the dark matter nebula [Mar Oscura](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mar_Oscura_Nebula) in TNG ["In Theory"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_Theory_(episode)).

[image: Mar Oscura Nebula]

I'm sure people can find more examples of the Mutara Nebula being recycled.

Comment: *But they get dull after a while* - good point, the fact that SW started as a movie whereas ST started as TV had been overlooked up to now.  As per [NKCampbell's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/119865/5930) the various Star Wars TV series have indeed made use of (unrealistic!) nebulae.  (To be fair, when we say that there aren't any small, dense nebulae as shown on TV, we mean there aren't any near us and we don't know of any reason why they should exist.  In fictional worlds where the physics is different to ours, that might not be true.)

Comment: There's even a *Voyager* episode where they not only reuse the Mutara Nebula but *call it* the Mutara Nebula, too.

Comment: @Praxis: Mutara _class_ nebula. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mutara_class And from what I can tell it looked nothing like the actual Mutara nebula.

Comment: @PreferenceBean : I was just working off of memory.  Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 6):

Define "Star Trek".  Not everything is full of nebulae.  In particular, I'm thinking of the original series, which didn't have any nebulae.

(It is possible that they added some when the "enhanced" the original series with CGI, etc.  I'll have to go check...but when they originally aired on TV, those shows were 100% nebula-free.)

Starting with "Star Trek: The Motion Picture", they started adding manymanymany colorful things, such as the clouds surrounding V'ger.  By the time of "The Next Generation", this was already a well-entrenched part of latter-day Star Trek visuals.

Comment: I have a suspicion that in the times of TOS and the original Star Wars movie, it wouldn't have been possible to make nebulae look as good as in the latter-day Star Trek.  (But perhaps there are counterexamples from other works of the time?  Or perhaps someone familiar with the history of special effects and their limitations could comment?)

Answer (score 3):

Very simple. Star wars got it right (or at least, a bit more right than Star Trek). Nebulae are very faint and without a big telescope and long exposure, you don't see anything.

Compare this with any real-world picture of a planet (or the Moon). As long as you have a reasonably bright foreground object, the exposure is so short that not even stars are visible, let alone nebulae.

The luminosities of spaceships/planets, stars and nebulae are *huge* factors apart, and even in observational astronomy, unless you *want* to see a nebula, you won't see it. And if there are nearby stars in the same picture, they will burn out the image (you'll see the diffraction spikes and bloom around them).

Answer (score 2):

Have you watch Star Wars Rebels: Secret Cargo?
There is a huge nebula here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a well-known shot of a nebula (for some definitions of the word) in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

[image: Final scene]

Comment: I always thought that was a galaxy

Comment: It is, indeed, a spiral galaxy.

Comment: And that's why I said "for some definitions of the word". Galaxies used to be called nebulae, and the Andromeda Galaxy was once the Andromeda Nebula.

Comment: That's more likely a star with a planetary accretion disc. I can't think of a situation where they'd have that view, to the naked eye, of a galaxy from the outside.

Comment: I'm not sure using outdated definitions count and in this case just come across as sort of misinformed, but then again my thinking might just be as flat as the earth ;). @user16291: true, that would also be quite a lot of extragalactic stars, and there isn't really any kind of mention of intergalactic travel. At least, not as much as is implied by this scene. I kind of feel it was put in because it was pretty, not because it was accurate. It physically could only be a star with accretion disk or else they would be far far away from their own galaxy.

Comment: @user16295 Per the script, it's a galaxy. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html "Together they stand at the large window of the medical center looking out on the Rebel Star Cruiser and a dense, luminous **galaxy** swirling in space."

Comment: @user16295: Optically, such a view does exist somewhere. It's more the background stars look wrong here. I suppose they could all be ejected globular clusters but that's a lot of them.

Comment: @Joshua The stars could be in Galaxy FarFarAway and the galaxy they're looking at is EvenFurtherAway.

Comment: @Joshua They could be in an orbiting clump of stars a few 100 light years in radius.  The nearest 50 ly to us has http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/50lys.html a reasonable number of stars.

Comment: So what you're saying is, it's a nebula... from a certain point of view.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I'm saying it's a nebula for a certain definition of the word "nebula", and an actual real definition rather than one I just made up.

Comment: There's already a [question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/where-was-the-rebel-fleets-rendezvous-point-at-the-end-of-the-empire-strikes-ba) about what exactly this thing is.

Comment: @MikeScott: Mason was quoting Star Wars for comic effect.

Answer (score -1):

Since astrogators wouldn't be able to spot the asteroids in time ...

Guessing seriously, assuming that nebulae and asteroids serve the same McGuffin purpose of impeding ranging and navigation or wreaking havoc upon space vessels, rocks tumbling through space produce superior visuals while they are much harder to render convincingly. At the time when Star Trek took off, the F/X department could not handle the challenge or they were able to do so but only at prohibitive cost and time.

Unfortunately I do not have references to quote.

Comment: I think you mean "at the time when *Star Wars* took off"?

Comment: @Schwern No,I don't. Star Trek dates from the mid 60ies, Star Wars from the mid 70ies.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking because Star Trek is all about weird stuff happening in space, and visual nebulae give a nice setting and visual for spacial anomalies and the like, whereas Star Wars isn't about that at all.

Answer (score -1):

One Legends incident during the Yuuzhan Vong war is the Battle of the Black Bantha, which takes place in the [eponymous "nebula"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Bantha_Nebula). The Black Bantha is specifically identified as in a transitional state: it's a part of a nebula that soon, in astronomical terms, will finish collapsing into a star, but for now it's still dispersed enough to fly through. This gives it an appearance somewhat more like a traditional Trek nebula. (I assume this is still not particularly realistic, but it's an effort.) Even so, the nebula's nature is not particularly important to the battle; the main reason it's relevant is because the (non-threatening) nebula is accidentally marked as a much more serious navigation hazard on most maps, so it's something of a secret waypoint for smugglers.