# What is the type/shape of the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

In our universe galaxies come in a variety of shapes divided in three main [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy#Types_and_morphology): ellipticals, spirals and irregulars.

What type does the Star Wars galaxy have?

I assume that the Star Wars universe has multiple galaxies formed mainly in the same way as in our universe. And there is at least one spiral galaxy depicted at the end of The Empire Strikes Back (apparently satellite to the Star Wars galaxy).
[image]

Comment: Note that [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/where-was-the-rebel-fleets-rendezvous-point-at-the-end-of-the-empire-strikes-ba/131247#131247) positively confirms that the galaxy we're looking at is indeed the [Skyriver](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35642/20774) Galaxy, viewed from beyond the Outer Rim looking back in.

Comment: Totally disagree. It's impossible to see the entire shape of a galaxy from the inside of galaxy itself, even from a galaxy's rim. For instance our solar system is located in a sort of rim of [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) and we can't see its shape. So that quote in your answer doesn't confirm that the depicted galaxy is the Star Wars galaxy itself. Conversely, that's a satellite galaxy observed from the rim of the Star Wars galaxy.

Comment: You're certainly welcome to that opinion, and you're not the first to say that. You should know, however, that you're contradicting the accepted response from the guy who now heads up the Star Wars Story Group. [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74365/20774) also deals with the issue