# Planet farthest from Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, planets

What is the planet farthest from Coruscant in the Star Wars Galaxy? I understand that this information might not be available. If it isn't, please tell me.

Comment: Farthest from Coruscant in what regard? Furthest reachable planet? Furthest within the galaxy? Furthest *how*?

Comment: If Coruscant is the bright center of the universe, then Tatooine is the planet that it's furthest from.

Comment: @LeoObsessedwithStarWars - I don't think Organic Marble was saying that seriously, I'm pretty sure he was making a joke.

Comment: @organicmarble - That's worthy of being added as an answer, even if Luke only meant it metaphorically

Comment: @LeoObsessedwithStarWars - It's generally considered bad form to edit your question to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @Richard:   Well, he didn't change his intent -- he was only clarifying.   We can't cry foul whenever anyone has a technically correct answer to the exact wording of a question and then seeks to clarify.   I happen to like your answer (see my comment) but I don't think we should be nitpicky and criticize Leo for the edit.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - There's a world of difference between "what is the farthest period" and "what is the farthest within a closely defined area"

Comment: @Richard - You know as well as I do that he meant within the same galaxy, or at least not our own planet.

Comment: @WadCheber - No, he originally asked which was the farthest planet, without qualification. Short of mind-reading, there's no way I could have divined his intentions

Comment: @Richard - Way to evade the point.  If I figured out what he meant and you didn't, that either means you're dense, which you are not, or you're being deliberately obtuse, which you obviously are.  Note that your answer relates to earth-like planets, which he never mentioned, and you assume without any justification that "far, far away" means "farthest away" which it doesn't.  Don't give the guy a hard time just because your tongue in cheek answer is not valid.

Comment: @Richard - It's generally considered bad form to make a joke answer and then whine when the OP edits his question to address the issue raised by the very first comment on it.

Comment: @Richard - Or were you under the impression that I'm a mind reader?  Spoiler alert:  I'm not.  I just use common sense.

Comment: @WadCheber - I'm wondering if the OP would have been more willing to consider extra-galactic planets if he'd read [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68436/20774)

Comment: @Richard - Maybe, but I never thought that he would  consider "earth" to be a real answer. He was asked to clarify his question almost immediately after he asked it, and he did so quite quickly, in the manner he deemed best. It isn't his fault that you rushed in with a jokey answer before he could make the requested edit. This one is on you, my friend. I'm a bit disappointed to see you giving a new user a hard time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Within the Galaxy Far, Far Away, it appears - at least from [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_galaxy) chart - that the planet furthest from Coruscant is the so-called "[planet of the Red Nebula](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Nebula)".

[image]

To save you from having to search for the relevant planets:

[image]

Comment: Could you give me the link to this chart?

Comment: @LeoObsessedwithStarWars - I did.  It's linked in the text.

Comment: @LeoObsessedwithStarWars Better link http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_galaxy

Comment: Three things: One that chart is listing (solar) Systems, not planets. Second, that chat is in no way complete. I didn't look closely enough to say if there are any canon planets missing, but due to how many systems there are in a galaxy, this chart can't have all of them. Further, new planets can get added to the canon. Finally, you might want to remember that this chart is the Legacies canon and not the new Disney canon. Depending on your purpose, this answer is likely what you want. Just some things to consider.

Comment: @Thoth19 - Please read the first sentence of my answer.  "...it appears - **at least, from this chart**". The answer already contains a caveat that it is based on the chart I provided, and nothing else.  As far as the distinction between planets and systems, that is an irrelevant point.  Planets generally exist within systems, and since the Red Nebula is farthest out on the chart, the planet within it is also the farthest out of all the systems on the chart.

Comment: @WadCheber I agree that your answer is good. It very likely is the response the OP was looking for. There are just a handful of subtleties that either the OP or future people reading this page might find useful to note. For the record, I thought you did the useful legwork and +1ed

Comment: @Thoth19 - thanks.  I'd actually be happy to be proven wrong, if there is a better answer out there somewhere.  I just offered the best answer that I could find relatively easily.

Comment: This chart always makes me wonder why after all these thousands of years, there are still unknown regions

Comment: @PlasmaHH Presumably because space is [really, really big.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/545402-space-it-says-is-big-really-big-you-just-won-t)

Comment: @Lilienthal: In StarWars it seems to be small enough for a quick trip from Coruscant to the outer rim. Quite the same distance as to these unknown regions.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Something do do with not being able to see what's around you while in hyperspace?  I would think if you have to putt around at sub light speed it'd take you quite some time to explore.

Comment: @emachine: We have a universe with many billions of life forms and many thousands of years of FTL travel. That is imho more than enough lifeformpower to explore. West of the core (and Coruscant) there is essentially nothing explored, but the main routes to the outer rims in the other directions have been established for a long time. If it was about distance to travel, then having a maximum distance from the most densely populated areas would make sense, but not that no one goes westwards.... As if there is something nobody wants to see...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Getting from point A to point B in space doesn't say anything about the sensor reach you have on the way. I don't know (or frankly care) enough about Star Wars' handwaving for interstellar travel to delve into specific reasons to explain the unexplored space. If you want to know the real reason it's there, it's probably either because the writers are lazy or (more likely) believe that any story involving space pirates also requires the map to feature a nice area to tag Here Be Dragons on to.

Comment: This is just a 2d chart and doesn't address how far the systems are out of the galactic plane, which can add a lot to the distance.

Answer (score 39):

Assuming the opening scrawl is correct, I'd say that the single farthest *Earth-like* planet that we know of (from Coruscant) would be Earth.

[image: A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away…]

Comment: He, he that's good ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, since the question didn't mention "Earth-like" and since we don't know the direction of the Star Wars galaxy for sure, it could be a different planet in our star system.  Actually, even if we did know the direction it could still change based on planetary orbits.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it shows that Earth is in the same universe as Coruscant.   It doesn't need to be Earth-like.   Since we don't know which direction Coruscant is from here, and since Earth is the only one implicitly mentioned in the scrawl, this is a technically correct answer.   I suggest removing the "Earth-like" qualifier from the answer.   (I would also note, we know Earth is not the farthest planet we know about, since we know of exoplanets in the Milky Way in every direction.   We just can't pick which one.)

Comment: Additional note:   To be doubly nitpicky -- technically, the scrawl doesn't tell us that the Earth existed at the time of Coruscant, so you can still argue Earth is not a valid answer.    Unless you believe E.T. is an Asogian.   Then I think you can argue "a long, long time ago" is millions of years, not many billions, so Earth already existed.

Comment: This answers fails the "in the Star Wars Galaxy" criteria.

Comment: @Mindwin: that it does, although that part was not in the original question.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: now that's clever.

Comment: Certainly some of the exoplanets we've discovered would be further? (though we don't know which ones, because we don't know which direction "far, far away" is.)

Comment: @lindajeanne - Well, depending on which way you'd need to travel to get to the galaxy far far away, those exoplanets might be closer or father away. That being said, the only earth - like planet that we know of outside the star wars galaxy is Earth.

Comment: @LindaJeanne:  That's exactly what I said.

Comment: @Richard:   Why do you keep bringing up "Earth-like"?    This was never in the question anyways.      And at any rate, depending on your definition of "Earth-like", it probably fails that test too.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_potentially_habitable_exoplanets.

Comment: @Richard:   I think we can safely say, we will positively identify an Earth-like planet in every direction in the Milky Way before we know which the direction of the Star Wars Galaxy.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking "in-universe" but aside from The Galaxy itself(but say ones that have actually had civilizations come into contact with The Galaxy still) there are a few options.  Yuuzhan-Tar, the original, as well as some of the planets from the companion Galaxies that have had invading hosts enter The Galaxy at prior times are all possible contenders for "farthest known planet from coruscant" in an absolute sense.

Comment: The text of the question has said "in the Star Wars Galaxy" for a while now, so these planets would not count.

Comment: @sumelic -- but that was added because of comments and an answer claiming "Earth", being in a galaxy far, far away. I think that other galaxies mentioned within the Star Wars cannon are true to the spirit of the question.