# What is the RotS Yuuzhan Vong quote?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith, quotes

I’ve seen it be [referenced](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68433/is-the-star-wars-universe-just-one-galaxy/68436#68436) several times on this website, and despite reading my copy of Revenge of the Sith, couldn’t find it.

Edit:
My copy of the book is Scholastic, written by Patricia C. Wrede “based on the story and screenplay by George Lucas” (front cover). It has a couple of color pictures from the movie in the middle of it.

Comment: Which version is it in?

Comment: @DavidW, I don’t know what version, but I put my copy in.

Comment: Presumably you're referring to [this reference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68436/101407)?

Comment: @DavidW yes, that was the reference

Comment: The 2005 novelization by Matthew Stover is [available to borrow](https://archive.org/details/revengeofsith00stov) at the Internet Archive, and doesn't contain that mention either.

Comment: This one was my bad. In my youth I foolishly trusted wookieepedia and quoted directly from it. I've since become jaded and now don't trust a single word they say. I've corrected the answer you're referencing; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68433/is-the-star-wars-universe-just-one-galaxy/68436#68436

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Valorum's updated answer on [Is the Star Wars Universe just one galaxy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68436/21154), this seems to have started with a Wookieepedia editor conflating the *Revenge of the Sith* novelization with *Revenge of the Sith: Incredible Cross-Sections*. The reprint in the Complete Cross-Sections book has the following:

> The Imperial Starfleet will justify its existence in unending war against Separatist holdouts, dissident rebels and even, it is rumored, **deterring barbarian invaders from outside the galaxy.**
>
> <sub>Source: *Star Wars: Complete Cross-Sections* (2007), page 75 (Star Destroyer—*Venator* Class); emphasis added</sub>

While this is apparently a reference to the Yuuzhan Vong, all this confirms in Legends is that a rumor existed that the Empire could cite the threat of extragalactic invaders as a reason for amassing a larger navy.

Note that this reference was edited out in the Canon reprint of the same cross-section:

> The Imperial Navy will justify its existence in unending war against Separatist holdouts and dissident rebels.
>
> <sub>Source: *Star Wars: Complete Vehicles* (2020), page 78 (*Venator*-Class Star Destroyer)</sub>