# Does anybody know the names of galaxies in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I'm trying to find out what is the name of galaxy where Coruscant and other planets are located. Like for example our galaxy is Milky Way, what's the name of that galaxy? I'm trying to find out, but I failed in my search, I hope that someone knows what it's name is.

Comment: I would assume their in one galaxy, the "Star Wars" galaxy

Comment: Really?When I saw a movie it was shown like small galaxies around the big one

Comment: "A long time ago in a Galaxy far far away" Are you sure you don't mean "Solar Systems"?

Comment: Solar Systems,are much smaller than a galaxy

Comment: I am aware of the definitions

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35637/whats-the-name-of-the-galaxy-far-far-away)

Comment: @AlexA - If that question Edlothiad linked doesn't answer your question, please edit yours to specify what you are asking about.

Comment: The "Skyriver" Galaxy appears to be the only in-universe name given to the Galaxy far far away. The smaller (dwarf) galaxies are unnamed.